# Emacs wrap-region-trigger has been overridden by ruby-electric-matching-char in ruby mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

Emacs 24, eLisp, Mac OS X Lion

The wrap-region-trigger has been overridden by ruby-electric-matching-char in ruby mode. How can I prevent this from happening, or just force wrap-region-trigger for ruby-mode?

Comment: I don't see any `wrap-region` nor `electric-matching` in ruby mode.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: I provided the functions associated with the keys (,[,{,",', and possibly others. I am not sure how to provide more information.  What is needed?  Thank yo in advance.

Comment: always start with `emacs -Q`, otherwise, we can't know what extensions you've installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can always undefine the keys in `ruby-mode`.  The following is completely untested since I haven't used `ruby-mode` for a long time.

```
(define-key ruby-mode-map "[" nil)
(define-key ruby-mode-map "(" nil)
;; etc.
```